# Cannot connect to networks (Wired / Wireless)

Tags: networking

I figured I'd try my luck here before trying a different distro:

I got a new laptop yesterday, installed Ubuntu over Windows, and couldn't get any sort of network connections to work, wired or wireless. I can see wireless networks, and attempt to connect to them, but the connection doesn't go through. Same with a cable.

I've tried a bunch of things (although not all combinations of these): disabled Secure Boot, tried 16.04, 17.10 and 18.04 beta, tried disabling ipv6 (this only causes the connection to drop immediately instead of a moment), tried a different network tethered from my phone etc. to no avail. Feel free to suggest if you think I might've missed something, even if it's obvious.

Here is the output of some commonly-requested things:

`lshw -C network`

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
   version: 07
   serial: b0:6e:bf:59:cb:d5
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:126 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:91204000-91204fff memory:91200000-91203fff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 01
   serial: 64:6e:69:49:d2:9e
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-12-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:23 memory:91100000-9117ffff memory:91180000-9118ffff
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`rfkill list all`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

`dmesg | grep -e e100 -e enp`

```
[    2.790248] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: renamed from eth0
[   25.833572] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
[   26.113377] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: link down
[   26.113664] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
[  246.501765] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: link up
[  246.501785] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp1s0: link becomes ready
[  356.459974] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: link down
[ 1654.639469] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: link up
```

With the last line appearing if I disable ipv6 (still no connection).

`ifconfig`

```
enp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether b0:6e:bf:59:cb:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 548  bytes 75510 (75.5 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 110  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 103  bytes 14579 (14.5 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 7050  bytes 429355 (429.3 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 7050  bytes 429355 (429.3 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 64:6e:69:49:d2:9e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 340  bytes 67484 (67.4 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 73  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 83  bytes 13795 (13.7 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

EDIT: This isn't really an "Ubuntu solution" so I won't post this as an answer, but just in case anyone else runs into the problem and tries to Google: I was able to get my network connections to work under OpenSuse (Leap 42.3 and Tumbleweed) without any problems, despite the fact that it seemed to be using the same drivers. For me this is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I have had an issue with that WiFi card. The wlp2s0 one. I fixed it by installing wicd, it’s another network manager.

I used this one http://wicd.sourceforge.net/

No idea what’s wrong with the Ethernet but I know the WiFi

Thanks for asking Ben

Edit: typed that a little fast I meant the network interface wlp2s0 was giving me issues. Sorry if there was any confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's not something I'd thought about or tried yet, but unfortunately it seems to be quite an effort to install everything by hand (since I can't use ethernet)– I'm missing a ton of python packages, which need more Python packages, which are not compatible with some GIR packages and ... yeah. I appreciate the suggestion though : )

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to buy a WiFi dongle and get the drivers for that so you can install a fix. It would a little less painful.

Hope this helps:
Ben